# Potential Memory Leak in rmi

Tags: java, memory-leaks, garbage-collection, jvm, rmi

We have a service that is being monitored via JMX. The JVM heap usage is growing and even major collections are not able to remove the garbage. Inspecting the heap shows garbage consisting of RMI related references (mostly, if not all, related class loaders). The only way to alleviate the issue is to issue explicit gc call through JMX (that removes all accumulated garbage). Our gc related options are:

```
-XX:+UseParNewGC
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled
-XX:SurvivorRatio=8
-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1
-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75
-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
```

And we have not touched either of: DisableExplicitGC or sun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval

I believe the problem is supposed to addressed by the code in sun.misc.GC.Daemon:

```
public void run() {
        for (;;) {
            long l;
            synchronized (lock) {

                l = latencyTarget;
                if (l == NO_TARGET) {
                    /* No latency target, so exit */
                    GC.daemon = null;
                    return;
                }

                long d = maxObjectInspectionAge();
                if (d >= l) {
                    /* Do a full collection.  There is a remote possibility
                     * that a full collection will occurr between the time
                     * we sample the inspection age and the time the GC
                     * actually starts, but this is sufficiently unlikely
                     * that it doesn't seem worth the more expensive JVM
                     * interface that would be required.
                     */
                    System.gc();
                    d = 0;
                }

                /* Wait for the latency period to expire,
                 * or for notification that the period has changed
                 */
                try {
                    lock.wait(l - d);
                } catch (InterruptedException x) {
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For some reason the above System.gc is not being invoked (that has been verified by looking at gc logs). Anyone has a suggestion as to how to address the issue?

Comment: Did you ever get OutOfMemoryError?

Comment: I strongly suspect you might not be closing connections/sockets properly.

Comment: @Nambari There are no connections to close in RMI or JMX. What are you talking about?

Comment: @EJP: When I used JMXConnector, if no close() I have observed thread count increment, you know RMI more than me, so I may be wrong on RMI.

Comment: @Meraman yes, eventually we do, basically gc gets into a sequence of gc calls that frees almost nothing.

Comment: @Nambari we have explored the connections/socket route. That is not an issue.

Comment: Which version of Java you are using? What are the threads live at that moment? If no reference to the object, they should be GCed. I would spend sometime on live threads at the moment and see if we can get any clues.

Comment: We are using: jdk1.6.0_45. Also, as mentioned, none of them have any inbound references and JXM memory call is able (100% of the time) to remove them.

Comment: @Nambari I didn't ask you about thread counts, I asked you what connections you are talking about. You haven't answered it. You seem to just guessing frankly.